# Trigger a query refresh (invalidate?) from onClick handler

Tags: reactjs, react-query

New to react-query. Have a pretty table with a manual refresh button.  The parent that owns the table and button row owns the query, and I'm passing a "reload" function down through props, which the onClick (a few levels down) executes:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   
   var qKey = ['xyz', foo, bar];
   
   const reload = () => {
        useQueryClient().invalidateQueries(qKey)
   }

   const {isLoading, error, data, isFetching} = useQuery(qKey, async () => {
      /* stuff */
      return response.json()
    }, {keepPreviousData: true});

   return (
      <ActionsBar onRefresh={reload} onClear={foo} onSearch={bar}/>
      <Other stuff...>
   )
}

const ActionBar = (props) => {
   const {onRefresh, onClear, onSearch} = props;

   return (
      <Button onClick={ () => onRefresh()}>Refresh</Button>
      /* other stuff */
```

Getting an error that "reload" is calling a hook but is not a React function component or a customer React hook function.

I suspect this is a useEffect issue but not sure how that fits into the above scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put `const queryClient = useQueryClient();` under MyComponent function,

and call `queryClient` inside the reload function.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const queryClient = useQueryClient()
   var qKey = ['xyz', foo, bar];
   
   const reload = () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(qKey)
   }

   const {isLoading, error, data, isFetching} = useQuery(qKey, async () => {
      /* stuff */
      return response.json()
    }, {keepPreviousData: true});

   return (
      <ActionsBar onRefresh={reload} onClear={foo} onSearch={bar}/>
      <Other stuff...>
   )
}
```

Comment: Duh.  Thank you.  Staring at this for too long I think!  Leaving it here in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to the accepted answer, you could pass down the `refetch` method returned from `useQuery`:

```
   const {isLoading, error, data, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(qKey, async () => {
      /* stuff */
      return response.json()
    }, {keepPreviousData: true});

   return (
      <ActionsBar onRefresh={refetch} onClear={foo} onSearch={bar}/>
      <Other stuff...>
   )
```